# ¿Cómo puedo visualizar imagnes guardados en mi CRUD del backend al frontend?

Tags: crud, yii2

```
    <?php

    use yii\helpers\Html;
   //use yii\grid\GridView;
    use yii\widgets\LinkPager;

    $this->title = 'Productos';
    ?>
    <h1>Productos</h1>
    <ul>
    <?php foreach ($productos as $producto): ?>
    <li>
        <?= Html::encode("{$producto->nombre}: {$producto->descripcion} - {$producto->imagen}." ) ?>
    </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>

    <?= LinkPager::widget(['pagination' => $pagination]) ?>
```

Este es mi código en el Index del frontend para mostrar la infromación

Comment: Y cómo está guardada la imagen? En HTML hay que usar la etiqueta `<img>` para eso...

Comment: Tengo un CRUD en el backend que tiene nombre, descripción, e imagén pero al llamar esta información al frontend en la imagén aparece el nombre de la imagen mas no la imagen.

Comment: Qué dato tiene `imagen`? Entiendo el CRUD pero no sabemos qué es lo que estás guardando. El nombre? Un base64 con el _contenido_ de la imagen? Igual, hacerle html encode a alguno de esos valores no va a mostrar la imagen automágicamente